# Unable to rename a large Hive table with large number of partitions

Tags: hive

I m trying to rename a large Hive table (managed table) that has high number of partitions (multilevel, two levels). Whenever we use ALTER TABLE command, it just hangs. Is it an existing bug in Hive ? Did anyone face this problem ? Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying ALTER TABLE command hangs.
So, try with import and export options in Hive.

By export --> locating file in HDFS

By import --> copying data from HDFS

EXPORT TABLE tbl_nm TO 'hdfs_location';

IMPORT TABLE new_tbl_nm FROM 'hdfs_location';

Visit here for more details..

http://www.aptibook.com/discuss-technical?uid=tech-hive13&question=Rename-a-table-in-Hive-%E2%80%93-How-to-do-it?